# How can I optimize this prime test to take less time?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to test for big prime numbers, but even with numbers that only reach to 9.999 it takes about 20 to 70 seconds to get the 2 primes I want and thats kinda really slow, so how can I optimize this test loop?(thats only the header and the loop; I can post the whole function if needed):

```
#include <iostream>

for (unsigned int j = 2; j <= (number / 2); j++) {
    std::cout << number << "%" << j;
    if (number % j != 0) {
        std::cout << "\tI\n" << std::endl;
        continue;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "\tX\n" << std::endl;
        break;
    }
    if (j > 2) {
        j++;
    }
}
```

Comment: `std::endl` flushes the stream and thus take much cost. It can be replaced with `'\n'` if flushing is not required.

Comment: There is plenty of mathematical theory in this area, specifically regarding quick primality checks. I suggest you do a quick google search. Continuing with your naive implementation, you only need to check divisibility by preceding prime numbers, not all natural numbers.

Comment: It looks unclear for me what you want to do. Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: How did you compile the code?  What optimization level did you use?

Comment: Ok so I wanted to test how much of an impact ```std::cout``` has on the loop and it seems like it slows it down so much that without it, it takes under a second to get the 2 primes...
Thanks for the answer, without it I wouldn't even have tried it :)

Comment: The second if condition is never reached. You can remove that and remove the `continue;` statement.

Comment: Instead of `number / 2` you can use `sqrt(number)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I solved the problem inspired by MikeCATs comment(I removed iostream), so I just answer to myself to close the question now :)

Well...I can in 2 days @-@

Comment: Yes the I/O is the killer here. Once you've eliminated that, there are still a couple of things you can do. You only need to test up to the square root of `number`, not `number/2`, although calculating the square root might turn into a bottleneck. Further, after you've tested with `j` equal to `2`, you don't need to test any more even numbers. So just test with 2, and then run the loop starting at 3 and incrementing by 2 (`j += 2` instead of `j++`).